# Kids stranded on an island with psychos

Tags: story-identification

I had a series of books when I was in high school - I think it was six books long - about a group of kids, perhaps adolescents, stranded on an island or a small grouping of islands. On the islands were a group of murderers; they might have been pirates or ex-cons.

Comment: So, which bit is the sci-fi/fantasy element?

Comment: Deserted on a tropical island? I dunno, Lost is on here too, so I thought it fit.

Comment: It's the prequel "Lost - the early years"

Comment: Lord Of The Fl- oh, never mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be the [Escape from Lost Island](http://www.goodreads.com/series/76159-escape-from-lost-island) series by Clay Coleman. It is 6 books long.

Someone else was searching for a similar sounding series on [WhatsThatBook](http://www.whatsthatbook.com/index.php?xq=1351) and the following description was posted:

> Various descriptions of the books:
>
> "After a plane crash, seven misfit boys find themselves stranded on a
>   subtropical island where a dark force stalks them,"
>
> "When seven boys wash ashore on a beautiful tropical island, they must
>   fight for survival against an enemy more fierce than they ever could have
>   imagined."
>
> "After their plane crashes on an undiscovered subtropical island, seven
>   boys must fend for themselves in a deadly jungle where the only law is
>   survival of the fittest"
>
> "Stranded on an uncharted subtropical island, the seven boys find hope when
>   a psychotic doctor arrives, promising to rescue them, but first they must
>   capture one of the techno-punks for the doctor to examine."
>
> "When two of the seven boys stranded on Lost Island are kidnapped by
>   techno-punks, their friends attempt a daring rescue mission using a hang
>   glider."

Comment: That's it, thanks!